# Look for a ceratin value in TreeMap and save it

Tags: java, treemap, type-mismatch, treeset

I'm having trouble while saving some information that I want to look for in a TreeMap. That TreeMap (tm) has a string as key and a TreeSet (Of objects that don't matter) as value. I want to find a certain key and then store the TreeSet in a variable to operate with it later. How can I do it?

It pops up an error saying  "Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to TreeSet"

As it does in the equals ignore case.

```
import java.util.*;

class ArbolS extends Arbol{
   private TreeMap<String, TreeSet<PLoc>> tm;

  public ArbolS(){
    tm = new TreeMap<String, TreeSet<PLoc>>();
  }

  public boolean Insert(PLoc p){
    boolean found = false;
    Set it = tm.entrySet();
    Iterator iterator = it.iterator();
    Map.Entry mentry;
    TreeSet<PLoc> aux;

    while(iterator.hasNext() || found){
      mentry = (Map.Entry)iterator.next();
      if(mentry.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase(p.getPais())){
        found = true;
        aux = mentry.getValue(); //Error here
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You cast to a raw type (`... = (Map.Entry) iterator.next();`). Try binding the generic type properly (`... = (Map.Entry<String, TreeSet<PLoc>) iterator.next();`). Look [@Eran s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47925475/4216641) for a full solition of your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should replace all raw types with parameterized types:

```
public boolean Insert(PLoc p){
    boolean found = false;
    Iterator<Map.Entry<String, TreeSet<PLoc>>> iterator = tm.entrySet().iterator();
    TreeSet<PLoc> aux;
    while (iterator.hasNext() && !found) {
        Map.Entry<String, TreeSet<PLoc>> mentry = iterator.next();
        if(mentry.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase(p.getPais())) {
            found = true;
            aux = mentry.getValue();
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I also changed the condition `|| found` to `&& !found`. You cannot remain in the loop if `iterator.hasNext()` returns `false`, and it seems you wanted to exit the loop after finding the first match.

Comment: Also, I would suggest using `tm.put(ploc.getPais().toLowerCase(), treesetContainingPloc)` when inserting so the loop becomes `aux = tm.get(p.getPais().toLowerCase())`.

Comment: Thanks, for both notes, it did work and indeed, what I wanted to mean was && !found.

Comment: @Turing85 Nope - the diamond operator is only allowed on the right hand side of an assignment (if the left hand side qualifies the type arguments).

Comment: @EduardoGomez  Enable all compiler warnings in your IDE, and it will tell you when you are using raw types.  Always address those warnings—they indicate that your code is syntactically correct, but logically incorrect, in most cases.